# How to display different format file with there thumbnails?

Tags: android

I am trying to list all the files and folders from Documentum repository(server). I have folder objectID and document objectID (getting from the server). I am using recycler view to list folders and documents. Here I can do is add image view with the folder icon and any file icons and display it.

But I want to see like this image shown below, which have different file and have different thumbnails according to their extensions. I will retrieve this all files from the server. 
[image: Want to display list like this with their thumbnails and options]

Comment: Tried recycler view to display the  list with folder name and added one  folder image to list . For document also doing the same thing adding one fileicon and displaying @Benjamin

Comment: show your code then

Comment: Actually right now I Don't have code with me. But i have reffered this https://youtu.be/mGTRNp6FbU4 and tried this thing. @Benjamin

Comment: `and have different thumbnails according to their extensions.`. Well you can do that too. What is the problem?

Comment: This is my problem how we can do this @greenapps

Comment: Well according to the extension you set an image/icon/thumbnail. You should explain why that is a problem as i dont understand why it would be. You already set a folder or file icon. So just expand your logic.

Comment: The problem is how it will detect this document is of pdf, doc or some other typ? @greenapps

Comment: Why are you suddenly talk about typ? Whatever you mean with it. You wanted to use extensions. And to everybody it is pretty clear that if you have a file with name text.doc what the extension is. Dont you see which extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need drawables for all filetype icons in your drawable folder. Once you have that, you can easily set the file icon in your `RecyclerViewAdapter onBindViewHolder`:

```
String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file);
switch(ext){
    case "jpg":
        filetypeImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.jpg_icon);
        break;
    case "docx":
        filetypeImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.docx_icon);
        break;
    //and so on
}
```

NOTE: This makes use of [FilenameUtils.getExtension](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getExtension%28java.lang.String%29) from [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)

To use with your project  add this dependency to your app `build.gradle`

```
compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'
```